# Logs reporting in a human way

Tags: linux, logging, web-applications, ssrs

I'm currently working on our IT System to improve it a little bit.
I've install set and run a rsyslogd on our servers (Physicals and virtuals), all of them now sending their logs into a database.

Now, I'm able to request this database to found any kind of problem or informations that I'm looking for quickly and efficently, on our whole system, but, yet it remain a "problem" for me which is to lay out all those informations in a human way for my managers and all other none technical persons.

I was wondering if their was a piece of webapp able to do the trick but surprisingly, I've not been able to find one on google.

So the question is, do you know the name of a webapp which is able to parse and report all my logs hosted on a database?

---

Wahoo, thanks to all of you for those amazing solutions.

I take a look on all of it, and I've to said that splunk and Greylog2 seems to be the most fitted for my needs :D

Thanks a lot, I'll have to make some POC now :D

Comment: http://www.splunk.com/

Comment: [graylog2.org](http://graylog2.org) (limited compared to splunk but simpler and free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the web interfaces for these two log management systems.

#### [Logstash](http://logstash.net/)

> logstash is a tool for managing events and logs. You can use it to
>   collect logs, parse them, and store them for later use (like, for
>   searching). Speaking of searching, logstash comes with a web interface
>   for searching and drilling into all of your logs.

#### [Greylog2](http://graylog2.org/)

> Graylog2 is an open source log management solution that stores your
>   logs in ElasticSearch. It consists of a server written in Java that
>   accepts your syslog messages via TCP, UDP or AMQP and stores it in the
>   database. The second part is a web interface that allows you to manage
>   the log messages from your web browser. Take a look at the screenshots
>   or the latest release info page to get a feeling of what you can do
>   with Graylog2.

Comment: Heres a nice blog post with a Logstash+Graylog2 architecture diagram: http://jpmens.net/2012/08/06/my-logstash-and-graylog2-notes/

Answer (score 1):

We use [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/). It has very nice web interface with many capabilities. More about splunk [here](http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAGNB). Additional apps to splunk [here](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/apps/)

We tested also [logzilla](http://www.logzilla.pro/). Logzilla live demo [here](http://demo.logzilla.pro/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

LogZilla has been around for 10 years, it was known as php-syslog-ng until about 2 years ago.
There's a free version for small networks available at http://www.logzilla.pro